# SQL Exclude rows on specific conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to exclude in my MSSQL View some results which are "duplicated with null value"

| stock_id | Current | BrandName | Made_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | Canada |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | y | USA |
| 3 | 1 | z | Nigeria |
| 4 | 1 | T | Cambodia |

So I want to exclude the stock ID which are duplicated and NULL in the columns brand_name and made_in. Results :

| stock_id | Current | BrandName | Made_in |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | X | Canada |
| 2 | 1 | y | USA |
| 3 | 1 | z | Nigeria |
| 4 | 1 | T | Cambodia |

thats my try but it exclude now both stock_id

```
WHERE table.is_current = 1 and not (stock_id='1' and brand_name=null);
```

Comment: edit your tags. mssql is not mysql

Answer (score 0):

This should display your null also
I apologize didn't saw that you are telling don't include id = 1 and brand_name = null

```
select * from tbl_stock where BrandName is not NULL group by stock_id
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

To exclude nulls you can use max function.

```
select stock_id,
       Current,
       max(BrandName) as BrandName ,
       max(Made_in) as Made_in
from test_tbl
group by stock_id,Current;
```

If you have nulls on current you can apply max(Current), too.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af6bfa7074c686a13bcee59c0f036ed1)